# Open a file with other extension using C#

Tags: c#

I have file with .xml extension. Using C# i have to open the file with another extension, like .exe for example. I can open the file with the 'Open With' option manually. Now I have to do the same using C#. How do I do that?

Comment: Wait. Are you trying to open a binary (.exe) file in Visual Studio? I dont think that will do you any good. I think you need to rephrase the question (I tried to clean it up a little but couldnt figure out what you mean).

Answer (score 5):

I'm guessing your question is that you want to open a File using C# with any program you specify.

You'll have to launch the file as an argument of a process that can support the file type:

```
Process process = new Process();
process.StartInfo.FileName = "SomeApplication.exe"; // The app to "Open With..."
process.StartInfo.Arguments = "'C:\\YourFile.xml'"; // The file to open
process.Start();
```

Comment: +1, because I think you can read minds! :D

Comment: @jonathon - Mind reading is a necessary skill for a programmer. How else are we meant to know what clients want?

Answer (score 1):

```
string xmlname = "c:\\test.xml";    
string exename = System.IO.Path.ChangeExtension(xmlname, "exe");
```

I reread your question. I think you want to start the application with the `Process.Start()` method.

Comment: This is how I interpreted the requirement too.

Answer (score 0):

Visual Studio's default editor for other file extensions is set in Tools | Options | Text Editor | File Extensions.